# How to ByPass/Mock Zookeeper connection

Tags: junit, mockito

I am writing `JUnit` using `Mockito` for a method which has the below condition:

```
if(curatorFramework.getZooKeeperClient().isConnected() {
    //do something
}
```

I have to test do something part. For that I am trying to Mock IF condition to true. I tried below:

```
@Mock CuratorFramework curatorFrameworkMock 
when(curatorFrameworkMock.getZooKeeperClient().isConnected()).thenReturn(true);
```

But it throws `NullPointerException` because

```
curatorFrameworkMock.getZooKeeperClient()
expects ZooKeeperClient Object to call isConnected().
```

There is no way I can create an object of `ZooKeeperClient` in my `JUnit` class. How to set this IF condition to TRUE through Mocking?

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a mock object for `CuratorZookeeperClient` and have that object mock the response for `isConnected`.

```
CuratorZookeeperClient curatorZookeeperClientMock = Mockito.mock(CuratorZookeeperClient.class);
when(curatorZookeeperClientMock.isConnected()).thenReturn(true);

CuratorFramework curatorFrameworkMock = Mockito.mock(CuratorFramework.class);
when(curatorFrameworkMock.getZookeeperClient()).thenReturn(curatorZookeeperClientMock);
```

Comment: I have tried it same way. It still throws NullPointerException in IF condition.

Comment: Even when you pass the `curatorZookeeperClientMock` object as the mock result to `getZookeeperClient()`?

This setup works fine for me using Mockito version 1.10.8

Comment: Yes.I have tried this before you posted this answer and it throws NullPointerException. btw i am on Mockito 1.9.5.
Can you please share the JUnit code with similar scenerio, if you have any.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit more wordy than you were hoping, but here is a test we're using.  Mock is used to simulate curator data where we wish to retrieve the IPs of Kafka servers needed for a Camel route.

```
@Test
public void testURIExtraction() throws Exception
{
    //Create a mock curator to return mock kafka IP data
    ExistsBuilder existsBuilder = Mockito.mock(ExistsBuilder.class);
    when(existsBuilder.forPath(KAFKA_BASE_PATH)).thenReturn(new Stat());

    GetDataBuilder getDataBuilder = Mockito.mock(GetDataBuilder.class);
    when(getDataBuilder.forPath(KAFKA_BASE_PATH)).thenReturn(_createMockData());

    CuratorFramework curatorFramework = Mockito.mock(CuratorFramework.class);

    when(curatorFramework.checkExists()).thenReturn(existsBuilder);
    when(curatorFramework.getData()).thenReturn(getDataBuilder);

    //create a kafkaURIExtractor object and generate the trafficeEventEndpointURI
    KafkaURIExtractor kafkaURIExtractor = new KafkaURIExtractor();
    kafkaURIExtractor.setBasePath(KAFKA_BASE_PATH);
    kafkaURIExtractor.setKafkaZKPort("2181");
    kafkaURIExtractor.setCurator(curatorFramework);

    kafkaURIExtractor.init();
    String trafficEventEndpoint = kafkaURIExtractor.getTrafficEventEndpointURI();

    Assert.assertEquals(EXPECTED_RESULT, trafficEventEndpoint);
}

private byte[] _createMockData() throws JSONException
{
    JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject location = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray ips = new JSONArray();
    ips.put("127.0.0.1");
    location.put("cluster", "test-mojave_dev");
    location.put("ips", ips);
    data.put(location);
    return data.toString().getBytes();
}
```

It is similar to your example in the sense that the method calls are nested. I.E. in order to invoke `curatorFramework.getData().forPath(...)` we must first address `curatorFramework.getData()` by returning a mock object of the expected type, which in this case is `GetDataBuilder.class`

The `KafkaURIExtractor` object simply checks that the KAFKA_BASE_PATH exists on the curator and then retrieves and formats the data, then returns it with `getTrafiicEventEndpointURI()`